# Potential energy for accelerating frames

Tags: gravity, potential

Given a large mass and a smaller mass at infinity, the total amount of work done on the object due to the force of gravity is -Gpe, for a given radius (r) end point. All fine there.

But a thought experiment: What if, at the instant the smaller object reaches point r, the larger mass, due to external force, accelerates in such a way that the smaller mass is fixed at the same point r above the larger mass? They will both continue to accelerate and the smaller mass due to the G field of larger mass will continually be gaining more kinetic energy even though it is at the same point r.

So how do you use potential energy functions to get around this issue of the same r point but still gaining energy? (I.e., how do I calculate the vector field for accelerating masses and the potential functions associated with this?)

Answer (score 0):

Kinetic energy is frame dependent. In the frame of reference of the larger mass the smaller mass is not gaining ke while while they are both accelerating and remaining r apart. In the frame of an observer considered at rest both masses would gain ke as they accelerated.